# error when trying to decrypt email address in vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, encryption, vb.net-2010

I am trying to decrypt email address in VB.NET but I am getting an error: "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array."

email address which gives error: abcadmin@googlemail.com

email address which works ok: admin@yahoo.com

Code for decrypting:

```
  Private Function Decrypt(ByVal strText As String, ByVal sDecrKey _
               As String) As String
        Dim byKey() As Byte = {}
        Dim IV() As Byte = {&H12, &H34, &H56, &H78, &H90, &HAB, &HCD, &HEF}
        Dim inputByteArray(strText.Length) As Byte

        Try


            byKey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Left("ABCD9876_", 8))
            Dim des As New DESCryptoServiceProvider()
            inputByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(strText)
            Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
            Dim cs As New CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateDecryptor(byKey, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write)

            cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length)
            cs.FlushFinalBlock()
            Dim encoding As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8

            Return encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray())

        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message
        End Try

    End Function
```

Thanks in advance, Laziale

Comment: DES is not secure.  Use Rijndael.

Comment: try this at the first line of this function `strText= strText.Replace(' ', '+');`